# Issue with 'for' loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cs50

This is supposed to be a trivia question website, which reflects whether the user's answer is incorrect or not after clicking buttons. My issue arises with the 'for' loop related to the incorrect answers.

```
            
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
               


                // Part 1
                event.preventDefault();

                let correctans = document.getElementById('correct1');

                correctans.addEventListener('click', function(){
                correctans.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                document.querySelector('#response1').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
                });



                let incorrectans = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrect')
                /*
                querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements
                that match the specified group.
                It's possible to loop over the items in a NodeList using a for loop
                */
                let i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < incorrectans.length; i++)
                {
                    incorrectans[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    incorrectans[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    document.querySelector('#response1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
                    console.log(i);

                    })

                }
```

Below is my HTML code

```
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                <p id="response1"> </p>
                <hr>
                <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
                <h3>What is the largest rodent on Earth?</h3>
                <button type="button" value="answer" class="incorrect">Beaver</button>
                <button type="button" value="answer" class="incorrect">Squirrel</button>
                <button type="button" value="correctanswer" id="correct1">Capybara</button>
                <button type="button" value="answer" class="incorrect">Rat</button>

           </div>
```

When I assign 0 to the variable 'i' before using it in the 'for' loop, debugging with console.log() shows that 'i' does not reflect the values that I assigned it, nor the values after it was incremented.

The 'for' loop only works when the 'i' is declared in the loop itself. Why is that?

And in the same vein, another question I have is that, does `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` always have to be used in JavaScript?

Comment: You've asked 2 questions before. On the first of those, two answers were given, but no reaction from you on those. Were they not answering your question? Then please leave a comment to those posts. Was there a good answer? Then why not mark it as accepted?

Comment: @trincot apologies for that, I'm a new user and was unaware that I was the one who needed to accept the answers and not moderators, I will be returning to check on my previous questions

Answer (score 0):

Event listener works asynchronously. And if you declare a variable outside of loop all events were not fired yet but loop has run. After loop has been run the final value we will get will be i = 3 (as for loop does increment once after ending condition has been met).

Now when we click on button and event listener fires. it reads value of i as 3 but incorrectans array contains only 3 value with index 0,1,2. Hence the error.

In case when declare inside the loop, the event listener stores current value of i. Thus running properly.

EXTRA :- To understand this properly what you can do is run the loop and then give i a different value outside of the loop like 1. But in that case if will not throw error but it will always red the option with index 1 regardless of option you choose.

Best would be to declare let inside loop. Alternatively you can also use this

```
let i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < incorrectans.length; i++) {
    let j = i
    incorrectans[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
        incorrectans[j].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.querySelector('#response1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
        console.log(j);
    });
}
```

Also no you don't have to always use addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded') in your code. But in your above code where you using event listener for dom elements. It is good to wait for them to load. Their are alternative like defer which indicate that this script is executed after the document has been parsed. You can use defer using

```
<script src="code.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`For` loop has three parts namely initialization, condition, increment. Initialization is optional so you can leave it blank. But if you put `i=0` in initialization part a new variable will be created for the scope of that loop. If you want to use a value from outside, you have to leave the initialization part blank or simply put the variable name there no value is to be given. Now, the issue you are having is because you are using a reference to variable `i` when declaring the callback function of the click-event and not passing  it's value. Hence, when the event is fired, it is no longer in the loop as the loop was there just to add the event-listener, the callback function gets the global value of `i` from outside the loop.

And you don't have to use `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` at all. You just have to either put your script at the end of body or if you put it somewhere else add a `defer` attribute to your script tag like `<script src="main.js" defer > </script>`. `defer` makes the script run at last when whole document is loaded.

```js
const correctans = document.getElementById('correct1');
const response = document.querySelector('#response1');
const incorrectans = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrect');

correctans.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  response.innerHTML = 'Correct!';
});

let i = 0;
for (; i < incorrectans.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  incorrectans[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    response.innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
  <p id="response1"> </p>
  <hr>
  <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
  <h3>What is the largest rodent on Earth?</h3>
  <button type="button" value="answer" class="incorrect">Beaver</button>
  <button type="button" value="answer" class="incorrect">Squirrel</button>
  <button type="button" value="correctanswer" id="correct1">Capybara</button>
  <button type="button" value="answer" class="incorrect">Rat</button>

</div>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your explanation! However, I imitated the way you wrote your code for the 'for' loop, and unfortunately it doesn't work, so I'm not sure if that's a problem on my server's part

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> , which is the same error as the original.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I replaced the `incorrectans[i].style.backgroundColor`  in the `addEventListener` with `e.target` because it will always get the parent that trigerred the event. Use hard-coded value only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: yep, i took note of the e.target, thanks! Also, since this question I'm doing is a part of cs50, there's some restricted access so I can't export the repository to codesandbox. I'm trying to work around that, i'll let you know when im able to circumvent that

Comment: it's placed inside the script tag.

Comment: hello, I restarted my laptop and my codespace after the night and it works now! perhaps it was some type of external bug in my server that led to it not working last night, but regardless, thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

i get thet the `i` isn t getting the decimal values,so after checking ur code ,i found the function part:

```
 incorrectans[i].addEventListener('click', ****function(){
                    incorrectans[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    document.querySelector('#response1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
                    console.log(i);

                    }****)
```

-u opened a function without passing the the `i` variable,thet s why u are not seeing the expected values, so if u want to correct this u need to put the `console.log(i);` out of the function brackets **or** pass the `i` variable to ur function.